# Can I lock android phone to one network if it is unlocked?

Tags: sim-unlocking, bootloader-lock

Can I lock android phone to one network? If can be unlocked if I have both lock and unlock code?

I want to lock my android phone to use only one network.

Comment: This question seems a little unclear to me. What do you want to achieve / what is the specific problem you want to solve? Can you add some use case and more information?

Comment: Hummm... +1 to ce4's comment - you have this question tagged as both sim-unlocking and bootloader-lock - which is it?

Comment: I can only presume that the OP wants to send in their phone for technical support and doesn't want to make it apparent that they've unlocked their phone.

Comment: something like that :)

Comment: @leki: Would you edit your question to better reflect your problem? Without knowing which model you actually have: Not possible (without enumerating all models). Some unlock attempts are reversible (Google line up), most are not (Sony, HTC,...) or at least are rather unfeasible... Search [xda](https://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=re-lock+bootloader+site%3Axda-developers.com) for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about sim unlock, it is possible to re-lock it back to the network as was often the case with old nokia dumb-phones. However, I have not seen this in practice with most phones now-a-days. Usually, once it is unlocked from the network, any sim card can go in place and use it.

However, if you're talking about locking the boot-loader - then that's a different thing altogether, hence my comment above to ask for clarification. In this case, you can re-lock the boot-loader, depending on the manufacturer and the procedure used originally.